# Where Are Databases Located - MySQL File Location

Tags: backup, mysql, database, mysqldump

I just installed a CRM application with a MySQL database.  I thought I new the name of the database but I can't find it.  Now I am trying to perform a `mysqldump` but I don't know the name of my database or where it's located.  Most docs I read assume the admin knows where this database is located and thee name of it - I should know this, I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: Thanks.  For a db dump, should this work: `sudo mysqldump /var/lib/mysql/db /crm/backup/db` ?

Comment: Uh, no. `mysqldump` takes a database name, not a database file.

Comment: OK, what if `/var/lib/mysql/db` = the db name?

Comment: I sincerely doubt that you have a database name with slashes in it.

Comment: I see, now I get what you are saying...  The command would be `mysqldump db /db_location/db`.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

If you can login to the MySQL server through a command line you can always issue a command to show all databases:

```
show databases;
```