# Where to retrieve MySQL Database Backup? Centos 6

Tags: backup, centos, mysql, database

Had taken a look at: [Where Are Databases Located - MySQL File Location](https://superuser.com/questions/145587/where-are-databases-located-mysql-file-location)

Didn't seem to help much.

I used this for a single MySQLDatabase backup: http://www.tecmint.com/mysql-backup-and-restore-commands-for-database-administration/

When I run the command for the Single SQL Database backup I do not find the sql in the directory that was given /var/lib/mysql/ in the link I gave above.

Where else might it be?

I am unable to use PHPMyAdmin either.

I have SSH Root and FTP available.

Comment: If your system is set up properly you don't have permissions to write to `/var/lib/mysql/`. Only MySQL should be messing around with that directory.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL backup should be in the folder from which you have run the mysqldump query. If you run the query from your home directory then the file should be present in same directory.

Comment: I have to log into mysql in order to run the dump command, maybe be more specific what you are trying to say? I checked home directory of sql folder, nothing of .sql is found.

Comment: @Travis actually you do not have to login to the mysql to make a db dump. Login to the server and simply run this command **mysqldump dbname -u root -p | gzip -c | cat > dbname-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.gz** Once the command finishes. you could see a sql.gz file in the directory in which you were while running the script.

Comment: I don't understand what script I might be running? Still no files to be found...

Comment: The script is a simple mysql dump. you need to replace the correct DB name, username and password in the script.

Comment: So now I am getting: http://puu.sh/5yy1y.png and I lossed complete access from the default login and I am now restricted to the serial console... Not sure what I might have done, I only have serial console access now and FTP doesn't work.. Any other suggestions from here?

Comment: I fixed it, ill be re reading your help @H4 :)

Comment: Make sure to run the script from a known directory. This command doen't require you to login to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you want fast and perfect backup, backing up /var/lib/mysql will be better as the mysqldump commands. It is better if you shut down the mysql for this time, if you don't, you will need a table repair if you want to reactivate an old backup. mysqldump is safer.

The simplest way to make sure, where are your mysql db files, is if you check, where are open files of the mysqld. This can you see with the lsof command, at start I suggest an lsof -n|grep mysqld